# BLOB database File convert to Octal

Tags: sqlite, csv

Using an sqlite3 command line i am converting a BLOB database file to a CSV file. The problem i have is that one column of the CSV columns is in Decimal and i need it to be in OCTAL. I have tried several Sqlite3 functions but has not worked.
The command line i am using to do the conversion is the following;

for %%a in (*.dB) do sqlite3 -csv -header "%%a" select car,person,country from log_data">%%~na.csv

To convert the column called "car" from decimal to octal I have tried

for %%a in (.dB) do sqlite3 -csv -header "%%a" select CONV(10,car,8),person,country from log_data">%%~na.csv but the function is NOT valid

Does anyone have an ideas how to convert from Decimal to Octal ?

Comment: Would sqlite [`printf`](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) help?

Comment: I have tried using the printf function as you requested - I have tried several ways of writing the scrips . For example for %%a in (.dB) do sqlite3 -csv -header "%%a" select printf(%O%,car),person,country from log_data">%%~na.csv      Note O is for Octal . I have tried different ways of writing this function but either i get an error or the conversion does not occur. Do you know how to write the printf function for what i require ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [sqlite doc on printf](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html#substitution_types):

> o |   The argument is an integer which is displayed in octal.

Changing this `CONV(10,car,8)` to this `printf('%o',car)` in the select should produce the desired result.

Since this expression  `" select CONV(10,car,8),person,country from log_data"` is in double quotes, the format (ie `'%o'`) has to be in single-quotes/ticks.

NB the "substitution type" is lower-case letter o.

Comment: Thanks !! - I had to modify it slightly for it to work by using the following printf('%%o',car) :an additional % worked for me